# Create table based on two similar values in different tables

Tags: mysql

So here what I'm trying to do.
I have two systems that are not identical in values but are similar.
For example Table1 may have the value `01234` for the ID but in the second table it will be listed as `someName 1234`
So I wanted to Trim the value from Table1 and do a like search in table2 for that value and finally insert the keys for each into a third table.
It tried a number of ways and failed getting what I need.
It tried the following but realized its just going to cross join on everything.

```
SELECT snum,shipToID,sdesc,clientStoreID FROM shipto,stores
where sdesc LIKE CONCAT('%',trim(LEADING '0' FROM clientStoreID),'%')
```

The tables relevant info is as follows:

```
stores
snum | sdesc

shipTo
shipToID | clientStoreID

shipTo_stores
Snum | shipToID
```

I'm trying to populate Table3 with the keys from each table(snum,shipToID) where the trimmed of Leading 0s clientStoreID is like sdesc from stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY with **[CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)**

```
SELECT CAST('01234' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Meaning

```
SELECT snum, shipToID, sdesc, clientStoreID 
FROM shipto sh
JOIN stores st
  ON sh.clientStoreID = CAST(st.sdesc AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Comment: Hmm I get a syntax error with that. SQL Error (1064): ... for the right syntax to use near 'INT)' at line 4 */

Comment: Seems to work as UNSIGNED instead of INTEGER Also added AND clientStoreID <> "" just in case. Trying it now.

Comment: Yes, My mistake ..  `UNSIGNED INTEGER`  should do it.